# IntelliJ inspection settings file missing

Tags: intellij-idea, application-settings, code-inspection

I can't find the file where my inspections settings are stored.
I looked in `~/.IntelliJIdea15/config/inspection` but the only file there is `Default.xml` with the content

```
<inspections profile_name="test" version="1.0">
  <option name="myName" value="Default" />
  <inspection_tool class="LoggerInitializedWithForeignClass" enabled="false" level="WARNING" enabled_by_default="false">
    <option name="loggerClassName" value="org.apache.log4j.Logger,org.slf4j.LoggerFactory,org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory,java.util.logging.Logger" />
    <option name="loggerFactoryMethodName" value="getLogger,getLogger,getLog,getLogger" />
  </inspection_tool>
</inspections>
```

I tried tracking the entire config directory with Git and change some inspections to see if any file changed, but nothing.
I also created new inspection profiles and grepped for their names.

Where are the inspections stored?
I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 15.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose the location you want the inspection-settings file gets saved. Go into Preferences->Inspections and Use Manage->Export to give a path of your choice.

(I believe intellij tracks inspection settings at Project level by default.)

[image: Img]

Comment: I guess this is what I want, but I'm still confused, where are the settings saved between launches? I guess that contributing to my confusion is the fact that a a lot of other settings are written to file immediately. Also it seems to use default settings for new projects but this can be changed in File->Other settings->Default settings...